# How to add a watermark to my RDLC report programmatically under some condition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, reportviewer, rdlc, watermark

How to add a watermark to my RDLC report programmatically under some condition (based on passed parameter)?

---

```
        overTimeReport.ReportPath = "Report\\OverTime.rdlc";

        overTimeReport.DataSources.Clear();
        overTimeReport.Refresh();

        //---- Generate parameter list----
        List<ReportParameter> paramList = new List<ReportParameter>();
        ReportParameter param1 = new ReportParameter("check_state", check_state); 
        paramList.Add(param1);
        overTimeReport.SetParameters(paramList);
        ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource();
        datasource = new ReportDataSource("DSOverTime", dt);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set background image for report body to your watermark image parameter:

```
=Parameters!watermark.Value
```

Set your conditional watermark parameter based on your "condition" (I assume your condition would either show watermark or not):

```
ReportParameter watermarkParameter = new ReportParameter("watermark", "", false);
if (showWatermark) 
     watermarkParameter = new ReportParameter("watermark", Uri(watermarkPath).ToString(), false);
```

Don't forget to add your watermark parameter to parameters list and enable external images in the report:

```
paramList.Add(watermarkParameter);

overTimeReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
```

Comment: I tried the above mentioned solution, but the image does not display to me when the PDF is rendered.

Comment: Do you have any error messages? Check your output window... Code above works for me in various reports.

Comment: No errors just the watermark doesn't appear on rendering the pdf .
`ReportParameter watermarkParameter = new ReportParameter("watermark", new Uri(@"Reports\draft.jpg", UriKind.Relative).ToString());
 paramList.Add(watermarkParameter);
 overTimeReport.EnableExternalImages = true;`

Comment: i use the following method to render the report:
`private void AddReportToResponse(LocalReport Report)
        {string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;
string[] streams = new string[100];
Warning[] warnings = new Warning[100];
byte[] pdfStream = Report.Render("PDF", "", out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);
Response.Clear();Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Application." + extension);
            Response.BinaryWrite(pdfStream); Response.End();
        }`

Comment: Few questions come to mind. What is the size of the watermark image? Can you try some other small image?

Did you try to see the preview of the report or render it into file?
`FileStream newFile = new FileStream("your PDF file name", FileMode.Create);
newFile.Write(pdfStream, 0, bytes.Length);
newFile.Close();`
Check image path - if image is really there:
`string imagePath = Uri(@"Reports\draft.jpg", UriKind.Relative).ToString();`

Comment: the size of the image is 2k ad i try smaller images with the same problem .when i render the report in pdf ,i find no watermark.i check the path `Reports\draft.jpg` and the image is already exist .

Comment: This solution doesn't work with me , so i create two versions of the report(one with the water mark and the other without) and change the path under my condition .